# Light inside the truck's cabin

Tags: euro-truck-simulator-2

When I'm driving **at night**, the exterior lights are not sufficient to entertain me. I believe that if there was a way to light the cabin and see the steering wheel in action, the game would be more exciting for me.

Does the game allow this? If not, does someone know a patch that performs this modification?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a mod to light the cab. There's multiple colours available but using white should sort it out for you. You can download it [here](http://forum.scssoft.com/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=2702)

If that link isn't working you can get it [here](http://ets2.lt/?s=interior%20light)

Other mods to add interior lighting [here](http://bestsmods.com/?s=interior%20light)